# ¿ Como indicar una clave foranea en Sequelize para relacionar dos tablas?

Tags: nodejs, express, sequelize.js

Estoy haciendo una **api** con **Node/Express**, conectandome a **MySql** con **Sequelize**.
Necesito poner como **foreign key** en mi **modelo Persona** la **primary key** del **modelo Pais** para relacionarlas.

Aca muestro el **modelo pais** que tengo en Node/Express:

```js
module.exports = (sequelize, type) => {
    return sequelize.define('pais', {
        id:{
            type: type.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        name: type.STRING,      
    })
}
```

Este es el **modelo persona** donde necesito poner como **foreign key** la **primary key** de **pais**:

```js
module.exports = (sequelize, type) => {
    return sequelize.define('persona', {
        id:{
            type: type.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        name: type.STRING,
        surname: type.STRING,
        // ACA PONER LA PRIMARY KEY DE PAIS    
    })
}
```